# Problems with multiple \starthanging \stophanging in ConTeXT

Tags: floats, context

I'm trying to place multiple figures with additional side text using ConTeXT one after the other.

When there are two figures in a row they overlap. How should they be separated?

The following code creates overlapping figures when I run ConTeXT.

```
\starthanging{
\placefigure[force][fig:first]{Caption 1} {\externalfigure[first-figure][width=\textwidth]}}
\inother[width=5cm]{Some text for the other bit}
\stophanging

\starthanging{
\placefigure[force][fig:second]{Caption 2} {\externalfigure[second-figure][width=\textwidth]}}
 \inother[width=5cm]{Some text for the other bit 2}
\stophanging
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Why use `\starthanging` with a figure that has `width=\textwidth`. Perhaps you can post an image that shows the desired output.

Comment: See http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/82188

Answer (score 2):

As Aditya mentioned, using hanging is the wrong approach here. In
the thread he linked to Hans and Wolfgang already provide two
solutions. I'll present a third one, based on Wolfgang's solution, with the following features:

- The additional text is typeset in the margin, not just close to the
  figure.
- It uses the margindata interface. This allows the margin text to
  be manipulated using the usual [ConTeXt interface](https://github.com/mojca/context-gitorious/blob/origin/tex/context/base/typo-mar.mkiv#L108-135).
- I attempted to avoid low-level commands as much as possible.
- The additional figure text is optional.
- Additional margin texts are centred by default. If the its height
  exceeds the figure height, they are top aligned.

#### The code

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]  %% only for the screenshot

\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided]

\definemargindata
  [FigureMargin]
  [inouter]
  [voffset=-\dimexpr\nextboxht-\strutheight\relax]

\definemarginframed
  [FigureMargin]
  [height=\nextboxht,
   align={flushleft, lohi}]

\starttexdefinition FigureText
  \dowithnextbox{
    \startlinealignment[middle]
      \copy\nextbox
      \doifsomething{\floatuserdataparameter{text}}
        {\FigureMargin{\floatuserdataparameter{text}}}
    \stoplinealignment
    }
    \hbox
\stoptexdefinition

\setupfloat
  [figure]
  [command=\FigureText]
```

First, an individual margin data set is defined. To correctly align
the margin text, it uses a frame with the [all the
settings that frames usually accept](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupframed).

Then the command `FigureText` is defined, which typesets the figure
content and the additional margin text. It is not responsible for
the caption. The command `FigureText` takes one argument, which is
the figure content. The `dowithnextbox` trickery allows easy access
to the dimensions of the box, which is used to properly align the
margin text. This allows the definition of the macro without a parameter.

The margin text is passed as a second argument to
[`\startplacefigure`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startplacefigure)
and picked up using `\floatuserdataparameter`.

#### Example

Here is an example how to use it:

```
\showframe
\starttext
\dorecurse{2}{%%
  \startplacefigure
    [title=Some figure]
    [text=Some additional text for the margin.]
    \externalfigure
  \stopplacefigure

  \startplacefigure
    [title=Another figure]
    [text=Some more margin text for the other figure.]
    \externalfigure [dum] [width=\textwidth]
  \stopplacefigure
}
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot1]

#### Caveats

The height of the margin texts is not taken into account. If floats
are placed consecutively, margin texts might overlap. Example:

```
\starttext
\dorecurse{2}{%%
  \startplacefigure
    [title=Some figure]
    [text=\input ward\par]
    \externalfigure
  \stopplacefigure}
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot2]